# login script with php mysql redirecting to login page everytime on server

Tags: php, html, sql

i have a login for like the following:

```html
 <form action="authenticate.php" method="post">
    <label for="username">
     <i class="fas fa-user"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" id="username" required>
    <label for="password">
     <i class="fas fa-lock"></i>
    </label>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" required>
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
   </form>
```

below is my authenticate.php

```html
<?php
session_start();
include('config.php');
if ( mysqli_connect_errno() ) {

 die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
if ( !isset($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']) ) {
 
 die ('Please fill both the username and password field!');
}


if ($stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT id, password FROM accounts WHERE username = ?')) {

 $stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST['username']);
 $stmt->execute();

 $stmt->store_result();
  if ($stmt->num_rows > 0) {
 $stmt->bind_result($id, $password);
 $stmt->fetch();
 
 if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
  
  $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
  $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
  $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
  header('Location: index.php');
  exit();
 } else {
  echo 'Incorrect password!';
 }
} else {
 echo 'Incorrect username!';
}
$stmt->close();
}
```

i have used the following php code on every header so that the user is redirected if not logged in

```html
<?php
// We need to use sessions, so you should always start sessions using the below code.
session_start();

include('config.php');
// If the user is not logged in redirect to the login page...
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin'])) {
 header('Location: login.php');
 exit();
}
?>
```

everything is working fine on my localhost, now i uploaded it to server, live the problem is even when i login i am again redirected to login page. here is my website for reference:
 [enter link description here](https://teia.website/admin)
can anyone tell me what could be the problem with my code?

Comment: What good is the link to your website if we do not know how to login?

Comment: @dharman can you give me ur mail id

Comment: No, I can't. I do not want to access your website. :)

Comment: Please post the (redacted if needed) contents of config.php.

Comment: What happens if you call [session_write_close](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) before exit() in authenticate.php?

Comment: Have you confirmed that your browser security policy is not restricting cookies for your live host? Also, be aware that people will be reluctant to visit a website that presents an invalid certificate.

Comment: I am new to this actually... Is it because of php version or anything... The server php version is 7

Comment: you website works well with out `https:`

Comment: To prevent that,go  to your `index.php` and call your `$_SESSION['name']`  if its not available. that page will redirect. do the same to all page that the user may access on login

Comment: @dean can u please edit my code and show me as an answr

Comment: call `$_SESSION['name']` instead of  `$_SESSION['loggedin']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have found out the problem, in future if anyone has the same error hope it helps

domain was pointing to .html website, so the php.ini file was not there, now its added and working fine

Answer (score 0):

Use session_start() before assigning it

```
if (password_verify($_POST['password'], $password)) {
        session_start();  
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['username'];
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;
        header('Location: index.php');
        exit();
```